# NetBeans does not analye php code behind the second symlink

Tags: php, netbeans, symlink, netbeans-8.1

I'm using NetBeans 8.1 RC2 for a php project.

I have this project stored in `~/ide/netbeans/workspace/myproject/`. This directory contains the `nbproject` directory and a symlink to the sourcecode in `/var/www/myproject`. In this project, there is also a symlink `./source/vendor/tueena`, that targets to `/var/www/tueena`.

So the file structure is like this:

```
ls -la ~/ide/netbeans/workspace/myproject
... .
... ..
... nbproject
... myproject -> /var/www/myproject

ls -la /var/www/myproject/source/vendor
... .
... ..
... autoload.php
... composer
... tueena -> ../../tueena
```

When I put the following file into `~/ide/netbeans/workspace/myproject`, or `/var/www/myproject/somewherehere`, then NetBeans tells me, that `IFoo` doesn't implement `Foo`:

```
<?php

interface IFoo
{
    public function xyz();
}

class Foo implements IFoo
{

}
```

But when I move the file into `/var/www/tueena/core/source/` for example, then it tells me only two PSR-1 violations, but not, that there is missing a method implementation, that is defined in the interface. Does NetBeans only follow one symlink?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve it. Not the symlink has been the problem, but that the library had a `nbproject` directory, too. After deleting it, the problem has still not been solved. I had to remove a line from the `project.properties` within the `nbproject`folder of my project. I don't remember the name of the property, but you'll find it, if you'll have the same problem.